# FFMPEG to make Quicktime reference MOV file from ProRes MOV source

Tags: ffmpeg, prores

I'm trying to figure out how to use FFMPEG to make a reference MOV from a ProRes MOV source.

I've found commands that will take  reference file and make a rendered ProRes MOV file

```
ffmpeg -enable_drefs 1 -use_absolute_path 1 -i SOURCE.mov -map 0 -c copy OUTPUTFILE.MOV
```

But I want to go the other direction. Start with a ProRes MOV and make a reference MOV that points to the ProRes MOV source.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg does not support, at present, exporting a MOV or ISO BMFF file with external data references.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess, we need to request this feature?

Comment: Even when implemented. you won't be able to reuse an existing dref.

Comment: Is the Quicktime library that is integrated with FFMPEG compatible with Apple Quicktime Reference files?

Comment: Not clear what that means.

Comment: Just wondering why you say that reusing an existing dref file wouldnt work if references are implemented in ffmpeg?

Comment: Because ffmpeg 's architecture does not support editing files in-place or treat media data as a monolith. The metadata of a QT or ISO BMFF file contains tables containing byte offsets for media packets, timestamps, packet sizes..etc. So ffmpeg relays each media stream packet by packet and constructs a new stream + metadata for the output.